# Simpler way to reformat text as numbers in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, currency, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a Google Sheets cell with content like this: £5,300.23 and I can't find a simple way to reformat it as numbers.

My current solution is in three steps:

1. remove the currency sign (`= substitute(A1, "£", "")`),
2. paste-special into a new column,
3. then format the column as 'number'.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Value` on the result of `substitute`:

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"£",""))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do simply:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A18, "£", )*1
```

[image: 0]

and arrayformula would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(A18:A20, "£", )*1)
```

[image: 0]